# Configuring DBUS to start JACK

Tags: configuration, jack, d-bus

I have the Jack Audio Connection Kit (JACK) installed, but cannot seem to get `jack_control start` to start the service.

I'm using Slackware64-current, which recently updated its `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf` to have a more restrictive configuration:

```
<!-- ... -->
<policy context="default">
  <!-- All users can connect to system bus -->
  <allow user="*"/>

  <!-- Holes must be punched in service configuration files for
       name ownership and sending method calls -->
  <deny own="*"/>
  <deny send_type="method_call"/>

  <!-- Signals and reply messages (method returns, errors) are allowed
       by default -->
  <allow send_type="signal"/>
  <allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="method_return"/>
  <allow send_requested_reply="true" send_type="error"/>

  <!-- All messages may be received by default -->
  <allow receive_type="method_call"/>
  <allow receive_type="method_return"/>
  <allow receive_type="error"/>
  <allow receive_type="signal"/>

  <!-- Allow anyone to talk to the message bus -->
  <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.DBus"/>
  <!-- But disallow some specific bus services -->
  <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.DBus"
        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus"
        send_member="UpdateActivationEnvironment"/>
</policy>
```

Ever since the update, running `jack_control start` as a regular user produces the following error:

```
--- start
DBus exception: org.jackaudio.Error.Generic: failed to activate
dbusapi jack client. error is -1
```

It did not do this before. The new configuration file says I'm supposed to punch a hole for it in the service configuration files. I'm not even quite sure what DBUS has to do with JACK.

Extra information:

- JACK2 SVN revision 4120 (2011-02-09)
- DBUS version 1.4.1
- DBUS-Python version 0.83.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out a while ago. Turns out it was a CAS-ARMv7 patch to JACK that broke DBUS functionality and I managed to fix using [this patch](http://lmsfm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lmsfm/trunk/build/patches/obsolete/jack-svn_revert-part-of-the-CAS-ARMv7-patch-that-breaks-dbus.patch?revision=703&view=markup). The issues were resolved some time ago in the JACK subversion repository and it works fine now.